# Excel 2016 DataValidation Error message not firing if no data is entered

Tags: excel

Not sure if this a bug or not:

I crafted a validation rule that makes a table field required if another field is a certain value.
Essentially,  if cell1 = "New" then require text in Cell2 by failing validation

My rule works but  my output message only displays if something is entered in Cell2 first.

Simple  example:

```
Datavalidation rule for cell2
Settings 
  ignore blank unchecked
  Allow: Custom
  Formula: FALSE    ( so it always fires)
Error Alert,
  Style: Stop
  Error Message: Danger Will Robinson
```

- If I tab past this empty field, nothing happens!
- If I go back and select the empty field I see small yellow Excel
  warning triangle saying "the value in this cell is invalid or
  missing"   - meaning the validation did happen.
- If I enter **anything** in the field and then exit, THEN I see my
  error message.

Since the whole reason for this rule is to make sure the user does not skip over Cell2, I need to make my error message appear even if nothing is entered in Cell2.

I could attach the rule to Cell1 but that would force the user to enter data in the wrong order to avoid the error message.

Any ideas on ways to do this without enabling VBA?